# I always thought mouth breathing was a joke

Tags: bones

After watching shows like *Stranger Things*, I just assumed the term mouth breather was a joke (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opUP0Nag9pQ). However, after doing a little research, it seems to be a legitimate medical problem that can negatively affect facial bone development ([Basheer, et al. 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4295456)).

Is it ever too late to develop proper tongue positioning habits later in life? Can the adult skeleton still morph and change over time or is this only possible during childhood?

### References

Basheer, B., Hegde, K. S., Bhat, S. S., Umar, D., & Baroudi, K. (2014). Influence of mouth breathing on the dentofacial growth of children: a cephalometric study. *Journal of international oral health: JIOH, 6*(6), 50.  PMCID: [PMC4295456](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4295456) PMID: [25628484](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25628484)

Comment: Can you please explain your question without resorting to a television series? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @user27343 - For future info. it is advised when talking about research conducted that you provide links to what you have found.  I have helped you with this question by providing one link.  If this is not quite what you are referring to, you are free to change it to a correct reference.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only in adults, even in children, if treated too late, the bone changes can be irreversible - they may not re-morph naturally.

The article linked from your question: [Influence of Mouth Breathing on the Dentofacial Growth of Children: A Cephalometric Study (PubMed, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4295456/) says:

> Because upper airway obstruction is an obstacle to normal dentofacial
>   development, mouth breathing children deserve prompt attention before
>   growth has proceeded irreversibly.

Comment: Some dental issues may be corrected with [braces and retainers](https://www.webmd.com/oral-health/guide/braces-and-retainers)